# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8'

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, utf-8

I used this script to scrape commentary on this website : https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

urls = ["https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=2",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=3",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=4",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=5",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=6",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=7",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=8"]

comms = []

for url in urls : 
    results = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
    commentary = soup.find_all('p', class_='review-content__text')

    for container in commentary:
        comm  = container.text
        comms.append(comm)

    data = pd.DataFrame({
        'comms' : comms})

    data['comms'] = data['comms'].str.replace('\n', '')

#print(movies.head())

data.to_csv('df.csv')
```

And I obtained this:

[image: output]

When I open it in Excel, it's not pretty, so I c/c and use Text to columns and I obtain this:

[image: output2]

It seems good but when I want to read it in Python to do further analysis, I got an error:

```
df = pd.read_csv('datajardiland.csv')
df.head()


UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 24: invalid continuation byte
```

I tried some methods found on stackoverflow like:

```
with open("datajardiland.csv") as f:
    print(f.encoding)

cp1252

df = pd.read_csv('datajardiland.csv', encoding='cp1252')
df.head()
```

But it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the encoding parameter with ISO-8859. `df = pd.read_csv('datajardiland.csv', encoding='iso-8859-1')`

EDIT:

Also, attempt to enforce the encoding while saving the CSV with `df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='iso-8859-1')`

EDIT2:

Since the data seems to be "raw" text with a lot of commas and periods. You can try to use a different separator with `df.to_csv('file.csv', sep=';')` and `pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')`. Or you can set " " around all text data to avoid the issue

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 8, saw 22

Comment: Uhmmm, I'd say that now the problem is the data. It looks like "raw" text with commas and periods along it. You could try to use a different separator with `df.to_csv('file.csv', sep=';')` and `pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')`

Comment: If that does not work, I recommend you trying to add " " around all text data

Comment: Nice! I'll edit the answer with what I said here. Appreciate you accept my answer :)

Comment: I will ! Just one thing, I've this weird columns : Unnamed: 0 How to get rid of this in my script ? With reset_index ?